# animate tableView row by selecting collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, nsdate

I have setup a weekly calendar with dates in a collectionView. Below this collection view is a tableview. On selecting any date in the collectionView the tableView filters data which works fine.

My issue is that i'm trying to animate the tableView rows according to the cell selection ie., if i select the next date(or cell), i want to do the following:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: visibleRows, with: .left)
```

And if i select a previous date(or cell), i want:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: visibleRows, with: .right)
```

Below is code. Any help appreciated.

[click here to see app screen gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9JUm.gif)

In collectionView:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! WeekHeaderViewCell
        cell.labelDate.text = calendarDateArray?[indexPath.row] as? String
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedRow = getCalendar().setArray("dd MMMM yyyy")[indexPath.row] as? String
        let dateFromString = getCalendar().df.date(from: selectedRow!)
        mainCell?.fetchFilteredData(dateFromString!)
        mainCell?.animateRows(animation: .left) // **help needed here**
    }
```

In tableView:

```
func fetchFilteredData(_ date: Date) {
        resultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(taskTime => %@) AND (taskTime <= %@)", DateHelper.startOfDay(day: date as NSDate), DateHelper.endOfDay(day: date as NSDate))
        fetchData()
    }

    func animateRows(animation: UITableView.RowAnimation) {
        tableView.reloadData()
        if let visibleRows = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: visibleRows, with: animation)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the gif image/video how it is showing right now

Comment: @Sateesh hi, i have added gif please have a look.